# Is there a way to Count & Sum Values From A Reference Column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with 5 columns.

- Column 1 is a Unique list of Names
- Column 2 is a Unique list of Tasks
- Column 3 is a Price For Each task
- Column 4 is a List of Names - Log File Column
- Column 5 is a List of Tasks - Log File Column

What I am trying to do is create a 6th column that gives me the total $ owed to each name. To get this value it will need to count each time a task occurs next to a name in column 5 and then multiply it times the lookup value of that task and then sum each task together. I know its kind of a big formula to do in a sheet and might be something I can't do, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So does each name that occurs in Column 4 also occur exactly one time in Column 1?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an odd set-up, so there's a chance I'm not understanding it completely. Here's a formula to try:

```
=(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$20,$A2,$E$2:$E$20,$B$2)*$C$2)+(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$20,$A2,$E$2:$E$20,$B$3)*$C$3)+(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$20,$A2,$E$2:$E$20,$B$4)*$C$4)
```

It looks at the unique name in Column 1, then counts the number of times that name was paired with each task and multiplies it by the listed price per task. Then, it sums up those figures.

Here's what it looks like in Excel, but it should function the same in Google Sheets:
[image]